# Undefined reference for opengl 4 functions (c++)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, codeblocks, mingw32

I've managed to create an apparently working openGL context and a window, but when I try to use functions from openGL 4 it gives me an undefined reference error. (I'm using SDL, by the way) This is what I've got:

(graphics.h)

```
#define GL4_PROTOTYPES 1
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <SDL.h>
#include <gl/glcorearb.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>

class OpenGLContext {
public:
OpenGLContext(void); // Default constructor
~OpenGLContext(void); // Destructor for cleaning up our application
void reshapeWindow(int w, int h); // Method to get our window width and height on resize

unsigned int vaoID[1]; // Our Vertex Array Object
unsigned int vboID[1]; // Our Vertex Buffer Object

void renderScene(); // Render scene (display method from previous OpenGL tutorials)
void createSquare(); // Method for creating our squares Vertex Array Object

private:
int windowWidth; // Store the width of our window
int windowHeight; // Store the height of our window

protected:
HGLRC hrc; // Rendering context
HDC hdc; // Device context
HWND hwnd; // Window identifier
};
```

(graphics.cpp)

```
#include "graphics.h"

SDL_Window *sdlWindow; //window program displays in

OpenGLContext::OpenGLContext()
{
    windowWidth=600;
    windowHeight=400;
        //set up SDL with OpenGL
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE); //set OpenGL profile
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4 ); //set OpenGL version

    sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, windowWidth, windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE); //create window with support for OpenGL
    SDL_GL_CreateContext(sdlWindow); //create OpenGL context
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(true); //set VSync
}

OpenGLContext::~OpenGLContext(void) {
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(sdlWindow);
}

void OpenGLContext::renderScene()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdlWindow);
}

void OpenGLContext::createSquare()
{

float* vertices = new float[18];  // Vertices for our square

vertices[0] = -0.5; vertices[1] = -0.5; vertices[2] = 0.0; // Bottom left corner
vertices[3] = -0.5; vertices[4] = 0.5; vertices[5] = 0.0; // Top left corner
vertices[15] = 0.5; vertices[16] = 0.5; vertices[17] = 0.0; // Top Right corner


glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID[0]); // Create our Vertex Array Object
glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]); // Bind our Vertex Array Object so we can use it

glGenBuffers(1, vboID); // Generate our Vertex Buffer Object
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]); // Bind our Vertex Buffer Object
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 18 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Set the size and data of our VBO and set it to STATIC_DRAW

glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); // Set up our vertex attributes pointer

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Disable our Vertex Array Object
glBindVertexArray(0); // Disable our Vertex Buffer Object
delete [] vertices; // Delete our vertices from memory
}
```

and main.cpp which I'm assuming I shouldn't include since it's not really relevant to the problem.

Comment: There is not a single line of code in this question that is from GL4. You have some VBO (GL 1.5) code, some GLSL (GL 2.0) code and some VAO (GL 3.0) code and that is it. Now, your real problem is that none of those non-GL4 functions are supported by the implementation of GL that ships with Windows (GL 1.1). You should consider using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net) to load the necessary extensions from your driver.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman ...Oh. I thought the VAO and VBO was from opengl 4. that was dumb of me -.- thanks for the quick response, ill try it